# Querying in advance with linq2sql for data with gaps

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

Hi i have table: Values with ValueId, Timestamp , Value and BelongTo. Each 15 minutes there is insreted new row into that table with new value, current timestamp and specific BelongTo field. And now i want to find gaps i mean values where one after another has timestamp more then 15 minutes.

I was trying this:

```
var gaps = from p1 in db.T_Values
                       join p2 in db.T_Values on p1.TimeStamp.AddMinutes(15) equals p2.TimeStamp
                       into grups where !grups.Any() select new {p1};
```

and it works but i don't know if this is optimall, what do you think? and i don't know how can i add where p1.BelongTo == 1. Cos this query looks for all data.

Jon told

```
var gaps = from p1 in db.T_Values
           where p1.BelongTo == 1
           where !db.T_Values.Any(p2 => p1.TimeStamp.AddMinutes(15) == p2.Timestamp)
           select p1;
```

Jon this last query is translated to:

```
exec sp_executesql N'SELECT [t0].[ValueID], [t0].[TimeStamp], [t0].[Value],
                    [t0].[BelongTo], [t0].[Type]
FROM [dbo].[T_Values] AS [t0]
WHERE (NOT (EXISTS(
SELECT NULL AS [EMPTY]
FROM [dbo].[T_Values] AS [t1]
WHERE DATEADD(ms, (CONVERT(BigInt,@p0 * 60000)) % 86400000,
DATEADD(day, (CONVERT(BigInt,@p0 * 60000)) / 86400000, [t0].[TimeStamp])) = [t1].[TimeStamp]
))) AND ([t0].[BelongTo] = @p1)',N'@p0 float,@p1 int',@p0=15,@p1=1
```

and it works unless all rows have the same belongTo, when there are rows with BelongTo with many diferent values then i've noticed I need to add to sql:and [t1].BelongTo = 1 which should finally look like this

```
N'SELECT [t0].[ValueID], [t0].[TimeStamp], [t0].[Value], [t0].[BelongTo], [t0].[Type]
FROM [dbo].[T_Values] AS [t0]
   WHERE (NOT (EXISTS(
SELECT NULL AS [EMPTY]
FROM [dbo].[T_Values] AS [t1]
WHERE DATEADD(ms, (CONVERT(BigInt,@p0 * 60000)) % 86400000, 
DATEADD(day, (CONVERT(BigInt,@p0 * 60000)) / 86400000, [t0].[TimeStamp])) = [t1].[TimeStamp]
and [t1].BelongTo = 1  
  ))) AND ([t0].[BelongTo] = @p1)',N'@p0 float,@p1 int',@p0=15,@p1=1
```

other words:

```
SELECT  TimeStamp
FROM [dbo].[T_Values] AS [t0]
WHERE NOT( (EXISTS (SELECT NULL AS [EMPTY]
FROM [dbo].[T_Values] AS [t1]
WHERE DATEADD(MINUTE, 15, [t0].[TimeStamp]) = [t1].[TimeStamp])))
AND ([t0].[BelongTo] = 1)
```

shoud change to

```
SELECT  TimeStamp
FROM [dbo].[T_Values] AS [t0]
WHERE NOT( (EXISTS (SELECT NULL AS [EMPTY]
FROM [dbo].[T_Values] AS [t1]
WHERE DATEADD(MINUTE, 15, [t0].[TimeStamp]) = [t1].[TimeStamp] and [t1].BelongTo=1)))
AND ([t0].[BelongTo] = 1)
```

but I am still thinking how can I add this to linkq

Comment: I'll leave it to Jon Skeet to answer since that is your hope.

Comment: no mate, c;mon, i am looking for all people help, if somone else can say anything about how optimal is this query would be great

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well adding the extra `where` clause is easy (and I'll remove the pointless anonymous type at the same time):

```
var gaps = from p1 in db.T_Values
           where p1.BelongTo == 1
           join p2 in db.T_Values
           on p1.TimeStamp.AddMinutes(15) equals p2.TimeStamp
           into grups
           where !grups.Any()
           select p1;
```

I'm not sure why you're grouping though... I would have thought this would be simpler:

```
var gaps = from p1 in db.T_Values
           where p1.BelongTo == 1
           where !db.T_Values.Any(p2 => p1.TimeStamp.AddMinutes(15) == p2.Timestamp)
           select p1;
```

As for performance - look at the generated SQL and how it looks in SQL profiler.

EDIT: If you need the `BelongTo` check in both versions (makes sense) I'd suggest this:

```
var sequence = db.T_Values.Where(p => p.BelongTo == 1);

var gaps = from p1 in sequence
           where !sequence.Any(p2 => p1.TimeStamp.AddMinutes(15) == p2.Timestamp)
           select p1;
```

Comment: in query like you said var gaps = from p1 in db.T_Values
           where p1.BelongTo == 1
           where !db.T_Values.Any(p2 => p1.TimeStamp.AddMinutes(15) == p2.Timestamp)
           select p1; we can't put two times where, nad p2 is not availible, i was wondering also why

Comment: @kosnkov: I'm afraid I don't understand your comment. `p2` is only available within the `Any` call, as it's the parameter in the lambda expression.

Comment: @Jon i am sorry Jon, you r completely right, i will investigate today what is the performance between those two queries acoroding to sql procedure , and i will give you feddback how is it translated, and what method is the fasted way to do it. Thanks you a lot.

Comment: i checked, both queries are translated to the same stored procedure:exec sp_executesql N'SELECT [t0].[ValueID], [t0].[TimeStamp], [t0].[Value], [t0].[BelongTo], [t0].[Type]  FROM [dbo].[T_Values] AS [t0]  WHERE (NOT (EXISTS(      SELECT NULL AS [EMPTY]      FROM [dbo].[T_Values] AS [t1]      WHERE DATEADD(ms, (CONVERT(BigInt,@p0 * 60000)) % 86400000, DATEADD(day, (CONVERT(BigInt,@p0 * 60000)) / 86400000, [t0].[TimeStamp])) = [t1].[TimeStamp]      ))) AND ([t0].[BelongTo] = @p1)',N'@p0 float,@p1 int',@p0=15,@p1=19241 and this is really fast

Comment: Hi again, to be honest, it doesn't work, cos join doesn't take belong to into account when join one table into another

Comment: @kosnkov: I'm afraid I didn't follow your comment, but if you could give an example of where it fails, that would help.

Comment: NB: my name seems to be the one having edited the question, but I only improved the typos of kosnkov's edit.

Comment: @Jon I edited my question and put pretty long explenation there

Comment: @kosnkov: So you just want the check for `BelongTo` in there as well? That's simple. Editing...

Comment: @Jon well, you are right, but what if there are milion values with the same BelongTo, therfore i would do it as translation for sql procedure. Isn't that possible to add extra parameter to join sth like:var gaps = (from p1 in db.T_Values
                            where p1.BelongTo == 1
                            join p2 in db.T_Values
                               on  p1.TimeStamp.AddMinutes(15)  equals p2.TimeStamp where p2.BelongTo = 1 
               into grups
              where !grups.Any()
             select new {p1.Value, p1.TimeStamp}).ToList(); ??

Comment: @kosnkov: That's what it will be translated to. Just because I've got a separate variable (`sequence`) doesn't mean those values are going to be brought down to the client. Try it and see what the query for `gaps` looks like... (And I *still* don't know why you want to use groups...)

Comment: @Jon, great Jon, this is what i wanted to create from begining of this post, you helped me very much. It works now great, i don't want to use groups i just put an example which is translated into the same what without groups. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
var gaps = dbT_Values.Take(dbT_Values.Count()-1)
                     .Select((p, index) => new {P1 = p, P2 = dbT_Values.ElementAt(index + 1)})
                     .Where(p => p.P1.BelongsTo == 1 && p.P1.TimeStamp.AddMinutes(15).Equals(p.P2.TimeStamp)).Select(p => p.P1);
```

Comment: i am sorry , but with your query i got this error: Unsupported overload used for query operator 'Select'. i changed it a bit to:var gaps1 = db.T_Values.Take(db.T_Values.Count() - 1)
                            .Select((p, index) => new { P1 = p, P2 = db.T_Values.ElementAt(index + 1) })
                            .Where(p => p.P1.InputID == 1 && p.P1.TimeStamp.AddMinutes(15).Equals(p.P2.TimeStamp)).Select(p => p.P1);

Comment: This is the overload I'm using http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534869.aspx . you do have `using System.Linq;`, don't you?

Comment: yep i am using.system.linq and this query is really giving me error Unsupported overload used for query operator 'Select'. Try your self if you can please.